# addEvent not working while setting a Slide element

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm making a HTML5 videoplayer with MooTools, and the progress bar is a 'Slide' element which I update periodically.

When I do that, any click event is canceled on that element.

Here's the slider:

```
this.options.timeSlider = new Slider(timeProgress, timeKnob, {
    range: [0, 100],
    steps: 1000,
    initialStep: 0,

    onChange: function(value) {
        this.setProgress(value);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Then there's my setTime function which is fired periodically every second:

```
setTime: function() {
    var percentage = this.options.video.currentTime / this.options.video.duration * 100;

    if(!isFinite(percentage)) {
        percentage = 0;
    }

    this.options.timeSlider.set(percentage);
}
```

You can also check the full code, you can find that here:
http://j.blck.lv/code/41081i1g3y2v

Comment: I don't see a call to `addEvent` or `click` anywhere in your pasted code.

Comment: See the full code if you want to ;-)... The way i write the event isn't wrong

Comment: You have to be more specific of what isn't exactly working - what line ? a jsfiddle may help here more...

Comment: The full code is available, but i found another way of doing it.